# Ads inside Flash application

Tags: flash, ads

I want to publish ads inside Flash application.
Do you know any ad-network that allows publishing ads inside Flash apps?
There is a Mochi ads network, they do publish the ads inside Flash, but they accept only games.
My app is not a game.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how this sits with Google TOS, but here's a random blog post about embedding Adsense ads in a Flex App.

http://www.ryancampbell.com/2007/12/11/adobe-flex-and-google-adsense/

Comment: Thanks, JStriedl, unfortunately Google does not allow to embed AdSense into applications. There are 2 editions of my app, one for web, and one for Windows (embedded Flash ActiveX). The solution proposed in the post works on web-site only.

Still looking for a way to embed ads inside Flash app :(

Answer (score 0):

I know you aren't using Longtail, but I think they do a flash ads program on Longtail Video... www.longtailvideo.com